What do we need to change about the chat session?
We have had three chat event sessions till now with minimal participation. The maximum number of people who participated was 3 in the first chat session. There was however significant interest in the idea of a chat session. Also, there are seven users subscribed to the event.
What issues do you see and what can we do to improve the event?

Side-note: I simply forgot the last time (1st of June). And yes, despite the reminder a few hours before.

It's not the ideal time of the day for me on that day of the week. Obviously this may be the complete opposite for others, but it could be the same. Granted, the Q&A-style in the original discussion doesn't lend itself to finding an ideal time, nor does the voting system unless you create one answer per hour of the day for every hour of the week (or only around the weekend.


Also the second time I could not participate at all as I wasn't able to go online (but I had mentioned that before).

There was nothing like a Doodle (use free text instead of calendar view), LIKE THIS ONE, to figure out the ideal time for the largest number of participants, instead a single time was proposed and we are trying to get people to participate somehow.
I think the fortnightly schedule makes no sense before participation has reached a level where people are aware of the event in the first place. More frequent makes more sense at this point. Every second week actually makes it more difficult for me (and perhaps others?) as I always have to figure out is it this week or the other? Instead of three we could have had six or seven chat events already with perhaps the same moderate participation each, but each of those events would have raised awareness for the event itself, assuming the participants would have differed.
The initiator of the chat event didn't show up during the first one. In fact we were only two people during the first one.


Ok. I am editing the previous post with a link to the Doodle schedule which you created.

@AsheeshR: think something went wrong with the edit and on meta I cannot correct your posts :)

Missed a bracket somehow. Corrected now. Thanks!

#1 all the way.
